# Running key remap script at startup

Tags: keyboard-layout, cron, startup, init, xmodmap

I'm trying to re-map my left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> and <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> to left <kbd>Alt</kbd>. So far I've been able to do it in terminal, but it never runs it on start up. I've read multiple Ask Ubuntu questions, but none of them have worked so far.

I have tried multiple commands and methods, but none of them worked

Putting the script in `/etc/rc.local` like this:

```
sh /home/dani/Scripts/altgr_to_alt.sh
```

Adding it in `cron`

```
@reboot sh /home/dani/Scripts/altgr_to_alt.sh
@reboot bash /home/dani/Scripts/altgr_to_alt.sh
/home/dani/Scripts/altgr_to_alt.sh
```

Putting it in `/etc/init.d/`

```
/etc/init.d/alt_to_gr.sh
```

Adding it as a startup program, the command being

```
/home/dani/Scripts/altgr_to_alt.sh
sh /home/dani/Scripts/altgr_to_alt.sh
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solved it myself

The second post [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=206&t=119441) solved it
Add the following line to the command field in `Startup Applications`

```
/home/dani/Scripts/altgr_to_alt.sh
```

And here is what the script looks like if someone is wondering

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Changing keys..."
xmodmap -e "clear mod1"

xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Alt_L Meta_L"
xmodmap -e "keycode 64 = ISO_Level3_Shift"
xmodmap -e "add mod1 = Alt_L Meta_L"

echo "Changed keys!"
echo
```

You have to make it executable if you want to run it at startup. I did this with
`chmod 755 altgr_to_alt.sh`

Comment: for some random reason I can't explain myself, this works (on ubuntu 18.10) whereas @mateusz-piotrowski's answer doesn't. (it seemed too me they would have been equivalent). Thanks to both of you ! I needed that for a long time !

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me as well on Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach:

1. Add the following lines to `~/.Xmodmap`:

   ```
   clear mod1

   keycode 108 = Alt_L Meta_L
   keycode 64 = ISO_Level3_Shift"
   add mod1 = Alt_L Meta_L
   ```
2. Open **Startup Applications** and add a new rule with the following command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && /usr/bin/xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap"
   ```

   This will wait 10 seconds so that it doesn't run too early and then modifies the keyboard mapping based on the content of `~/.Xmodmap` which is a pretty standard file for keeping a remapping configuration.

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me on ubuntu 18.10

Comment: @NicolasMarshall I'm not using Ubuntu anymore. I switched to FreeBSD and never looked back.